# Generate PDF/HTML from Doxygen's Docbook Output

Tags: pdf, documentation, doxygen, docbook

Doxygen 1.8.4 included a patch which adds Docbook support. This can be enabled via GENERATE_DOCBOOK.  I've tried it with an existing code base and I am able to generate a `docbook` directory containing xml files.

- How can I generate a PDF file from that output?
- How can I view the docbook output in a web browser?  This question may not be relevant if the content will be identical to the standard doxygen output, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

The Dockbook specialization contains many XSL conversions including HTML and XSL FO to obtain PDF. I would suggest searching Docbook and download these.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way:

- Install Eclipse
- Go to Eclipse Marketplace, search for docbook and install DEP4E from there
- Create DocBook project
- Replace the existing docbook with yours
- Run build.xml - Ant will ask you in which formats to publish the book. Choose PDF.

Comment: I installed DEP4E, but I don't see DocBook in any of the New->Project options.  I'm running the Kepler SR1 version of Eclipse CDT.

Comment: It is not in Project. It is immediately in New item, I have it above the Project subitem

Comment: But I have it in Project, too. Kepler SR1, too. Have you restarted Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I've restarted it several times.  The "New" menu starts with Makefile Project with Existing Code, C++ Project, C Project, and Project...  No DocBook in sight.

Comment: Check Help-about-installation details. The first (or the last) plugin should be DEP4E. Is it? If not, it is not installed.

Comment: Name: DEP4E - Feature, Version: 2013.10.2 is installed.

Comment: I have the same :-(. Have you a fresh Eclipse installation, or an old one, with other plugins? I started from Standard Eclipse. It looks as conflicts